# How to inject a value to event parameter to the 'lambda_handler' for testing purpose?

Tags: aws-lambda

This is the function signature of the `lambda_handler` of the entry point of an AWS lambda function

```
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
```

For testing purpose, I want to be able to include some dummy values in `event` dictionary.

e.g.

```
 environment = event['environment']
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can achieve it by creating a test event. For example:

[image]

Then I can apply it by using the `Test` button